# Problems with JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm new to Java and have hit a wall with JButton. I am trying to do something so simple in other languages but I am getting the following message when I try to add a button to a frame.

The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

Code is:

```
package testInput;

import javax.swing.*;

public class UserInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JButton click = new JButton("Click");
        frame.add(click);
   }

}
```

Comment: This looks to be an Eclipse bug, not a problem with your code. Clean/rebuild the project, or close and re-open Eclipse.

Comment: Installed netbeans  and there is no problem at all  - fixed.